# What conversion happens when we use "while" in C++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, boolean, implicit-conversion, boolean-expression

I'm using the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/while-statement-cpp?view=msvc-160) and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/while) as background. Microsoft's site says that the expression to be evaluated in `while` must be an integral type, a `pointer` type or some conversible to these. Cppreference's site although says that while expects a `bool` type expression.

What does really happen? The expression will be converted to `bool` or not necessarly?If I use, for example, a `char` type expression inside a while, wont it be necessary to be converted to `bool`?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Maybe confusion between C (expression has integral type) and C++ (expression is `bool`)?

Comment: It needs a type what can be implicitly casted to `bool`

Comment: Keep in mind that the distinction between int, ptr and bool is more what you'd call a guideline than actual rule.

Comment: In the end, the *{conditional}* expression in a `while` loop must be convertible to a Boolean value.  There are rules for converting types and expressions to Boolean results.

Comment: `bool` _is_ an integral type, therefore the MS documentation is correct. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while) is also correct as they state _"any expression which is contextually convertible to bool..."_.

Comment: BTW: what is _cppreference_ anyway? Is it [`https://en.cppreference.com/`](https://en.cppreference.com/)?

Comment: Yes, I edited. It was just to reduce text.

Comment: Microsoft's C++ documentation is pretty hit-and-miss; some parts are very good, and some parts seem to be written by interns or volunteers with little knowledge of the language.

Comment: Please provide respective link to https://learn.microsoft.com or provide a quote of problematic documentation when you are referring to it. It is more probable that you have misunderstood something and now you are asking to explain you how you describe it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According for example to the C++ 14 Standard (6.4 Selection statements)

> 2 The rules for conditions apply both to selection-statements and to
> the for and while statements
>
> 4. ...The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the
>    expression, contextually converted to bool for statements other than
>    switch; if that conversion is ill-formed, the program is ill-formed.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    operator int() const { return 1; };
};

int main() 
{
    A a;

    while ( a ) break;
    
    return 0;
}
```

At first the object `a` is converted to the type `int` using the user defined conversion operator

```
operator int() const { return 1; };
```

After that there is applied the standard conversion from the type `int` to the type `bool`.

From the C++ 14 Standard (4 Standard conversions)

> 7 [ Note: For class types, user-defined conversions are considered as
> well; see 12.3. In general, an implicit conversion sequence (13.3.3.1)
> consists of a standard conversion sequence followed by a user-defined
> conversion followed by another standard conversion sequence. — end
> note ]

Comment: I'm not used to search directly in official documentation, but It seems the best option always.

Comment: I don't understand why the object 'a' is converted to type 'int' in the first place.  This is a user-defined conversion.  But it should be a conversion that converts to 'bool'  - not 'int'.  And clause 7 means only 1 user-defined conversion is allowed (i) standard conversion ii) user-defined conversion, followed by iii) another standard conversion.

Comment: ...and user-defined conversion to 'bool' is undefined for our class A which means converting to 'bool' should be  invalid. So why does it try to convert from 'a' to 'int'?

Comment: @JavaMan At first there is applied the user-defined conversion to int and then the standard conversion from int to bool.  The compiler searches ways to make the expression valid.  See the last quote from teh C Standard provided in the answer.

Comment: this is my problem, clause 7 above is actually too vague to imply that compilers MUST consider 'int' conversion function if a 'bool' conversion function does not exist.

Comment: interestingly, chatgpt says: No, you cannot directly use a user-defined class with only a conversion function for int as a condition in C++.
In C++, the condition in an if statement must evaluate to a boolean value (true /false). When you use a user-defined class in a condition, the compiler expects an expression that can be implicitly converted to bool. The presence of a conversion function for int in the class does not automatically enable the class to be used as a condition.
However, you can define a conversion operator to bool explicitly in your class to enable its usage in a condition.

Comment: @JavaMan You are contradicting yourself. You have said that  "When you use a user-defined class in a condition, the compiler expects an expression that can be implicitly converted to bool."  And an expression of the type int can be implicitly convrted to bool. Thus there are used two implicit conversions: the user-defined conversion from an object of the class type to int and standard conversion from int to bool.